# firebase equalTo database query command

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var ref = db.ref("main") 
var usersRef = ref.child("users");
var accountIdVal = 56473;
```

What datatype is the equalTo query commmand using when I try to search with a variable, like below it does not return the desired result.

```
usersRef.orderByChild("accountID").equalTo(accountIdVal).once("value",function(snapshot){
    //returns all the values in users
 });
```

when the same thing is tried with non referenced value like below it works fine

```
 usersRef.orderByChild("accountID").equalTo(56473).once("value",function(snapshot){
    //returns the exact user
 });
```

even when I use accountIdVal.toString() it does not seem to work, am I missing something here?

Comment: There is no difference between using an int value as a parameter or passing the literal value. Can you reproduce the problem in a jsbin (or [tonic](https://tonicdev.com/npm/firebase) if it is node-specific) for me to have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the help I figured out the answer it was because I was getting the value of the variable as a Long, it was checking for a Integer and not a string so the datatypes were not matching up.